# Como habilitar cascade apenas para um model

Tags: entity-framework-6

Por padrão o EF6 vem habilitado para deletar em cascade os models, até utilizamos a seguinte convenção:

```
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Segundo minhas pesquisas não permite deletar o cascade.

Eu tenho um model:

```
public class Cliente {

   public ICollection<Contato> Contatos {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Contrato> Contratos {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Funcionario> Funcionarios {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Fornecedor> Fornecedores {get;set}
   etc...
}
```

Meu Model Cliente, há inúmeras listas, mas eu gostaria de que, se ele não tiver nada, em nenhuma das listas, mas tiver apenas na lista de Contatos, ele possa ser deletado em cascade, evitando erros...Aí se caso, ele tiver dados além da lista de Contatos, ele vá dar erro...

A ideia é:

Se o Cliente, tiver apenas a lista de Contatos como referência, então ele pode excluir tudo, Cliente e seus Contatos

Caso ele tenha outros vinculos, então ele não poderá excluir.

Motivo:

Acho eu que perderia muito em performance, se eu fosse consultar todas as listas antes de remover...e também, poderá ser inverso e não terei a lista, mas ele haverá referência...

Existe como habilitar o cascade apenas para uma propriedade ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independente de você ter as convenções no modelo (e que algumas talvez não possam ser removidas) você pode, sim, habilitar o cascade conforme você preferir, veja só:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // com cascade
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasRequired(r => r.Client)
            .WithMany(t => t.Contacts)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        // sem cascade
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasRequired(r => r.Client)
            .WithMany(t => t.Employees)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Não se preocupe com a convenção `OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`, ela somente se aplica à propriedades que não foram configuradas anteriormente:

```
// trecho do código da convenção OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention 
var configuration = edmDataModelItem.GetConfiguration() as NavigationPropertyConfiguration;

if ((configuration != null)
    && (configuration.DeleteAction != null))
{
    return;
}
```

Referência: [OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/ModelConfiguration/Conventions/Edm/OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention.cs)

Observe como fica a configuração das tabelas após a criação de uma migração:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Contacts",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            ClientId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Clients", t => t.ClientId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.ClientId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Employees",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Name = c.String(),
            ClientId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Clients", t => t.ClientId)
    .Index(t => t.ClientId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Minha aplicação coloquei os seguintes comandos e resolver o problema que você relatou:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); 
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Faz isso que vai resolver.

Answer (score 0):

O cascade delete existe em duas formas: o cascade que você aplica na FK no próprio banco e o cascade do EF.

Assim, você tem as seguintes opções:

1) A tradicional FK no banco de dados com cascade delete. Assim o banco toma conta de excluir os registros relacionados, independentemente de estes registros estarem carregados e trackeados pelo EF.

2) Alterar o relacionamento no seu modelo para refletir a obrigatoriedade.

```
public class Contato {

   [Required]
   public Cliente Cliente {get;set;}
}
```

Para isso os contatos do cliente terão que estar carregados pelo EF.